# backup folders using cmd

Tags: cmd, backup

I am trying to make a backup script using cmd.
This is my code so far:

```
X:
MKDIR "2017MMDD XXX Restore Profile"
CD "X:\2017MMDD XXX Restore Profile"
MKDIR "Desktop"
MKDIR "Favorites"
MKDIR "My Documents"
MKDIR "Pictures"
MKDIR "Videos"
XCOPY "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop" "X:\2017MMDD XXX Restore    Profile\Desktop"
XCOPY "C:\Users\%username%\Favorites" "X:\2017MMDD XXX Restore Profile\Favorites"
XCOPY "C:\Users\%username%\Documents" "X:\2017MMDD XXX Restore Profile\My Documents"
XCOPY "C:\Users\%username%\Pictures" "X:\2017MMDD XXX Restore Profile\Pictures"
XCOPY "C:\Users\%username%\Videoes" "X:\2017MMDD XXX Restore Profile\Videos"



Pause
```

The problem is that it only copies the files and not the folder (If there are any). I need a function that will copy both files and folders.

BONUS, is there any command for cmd to write the date? (Instead of 2017MMDD, where you need to fill out the rest) :)

Comment: I figured it out, the only thing now is how to get it to make the date automaticly.

Comment: What about reading the help of the command you are using? type `xcopy /?` into a new command prompt window to get it. Concerning the date part: search this site, there are plenty of questions and answers about that. There are too many spaces in `X:\2017MMDD XXX Restore    Profile\Desktop`!

Comment: As I said, I got it to Work. The Spaces wasn´t a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your date part problem: the command [`date /t`](http://ss64.com/nt/date.html) can give you the current date. A "shortcut" for that command is the dynamic environment variable `%date%` (only if you didn't override that variable with some other value). If you combine one of the two with a [`for f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) you can easily extract the year, the month and the day given the format of your date. Before I show you the solution I'll have to warn you: **the [format](http://ss64.com/nt/date.html) in which the `date /t` command and the `%date%` variable return the date depends on your settings** (I think location AND/OR language settings, probably depends on windows version). In my case the format was `dd DD/MM/YYYY` with:

- `dd` two letters of the name of the day of the week
- `DD` the current day of the month (the 2 digits format)
- `MM` the current month of the year (the 2 digits format)
- `YYYY` the current year (4 digits format)

So **on my side**, in order to get the day, the month and the year I had to use the [`for f`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) on this way: use `/` and  (whitespace) as delimiters and extract the 2nd, 3rd and 4th fields respectively representing the day, the month and the year.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%G IN ("%date%") DO (
    set day=%%G
    set month=%%H
    set year=%%I
)
echo day:   %day%
echo month: %month%
echo year:  %year%
```